# Does the Protagonist know that he is giving the 241 to ~Protagonist in the car chase sequence?

Tags: tenet

When ~Protagonist goes to the car sequence, from his POV we see ~Sator throwing the orange case back to the Protagonist and the 241/metal cube rattling around in ~Protagonist's car before flying out the window and returning to the Protagonist's hands.

From the Protagonist's POV, the Protagonist first throws the empty orange case to ~Sator and then throws the 241/metal cube to ~Protagonist.

Does the Protagonist know that he is throwing the 241 to ~Protagonist, and if so why were neither of them annihilated?  If he didn't know he was throwing it to ~Protagonist, did he just think he would return to the crashed car later (i.e. after the crazy car sequence) and retrieve it?

Comment: Why would they annihilate in any event? Physical contact is required for that, not just throwing things to each other.

Comment: I thought there would be annihilation if you saw yourself.  It is OK for a non-inverted person to see their inverted self?   Bigger question is why did Protagonist throw the 241 to ~Protagonist?  Did he understand that that was what he was doing?

Comment: Well, they even fight with each other in the Freeport vault. Bare skin contact is required for annihilation, Wheeler explains that when she briefs him right after his first inversion at the Sator's warehouse. We don't know what he was thinking when throwing the 241. Perhaps just to stash it temporarily to retrieve later. Obviously he could not know that the driver was himself inverted.

Comment: OK-you are right re: annihilation.

Comment: With regards to what Protagonist was thinking when he threw the 241,it seems to me that it would have been better to just keep it/hang onto it or give it to Neil rather than throw it to a random stranger unless the Protagonist knew it wasn't a random stranger and that it was ~Protagonist.

Comment: The protagonist saw the reversed car was being driven by the ~Protagonist. (Just like ~Sator did, hence wrecking the car). This is why he tosses it into the car. But Sator sees this transaction in reverse. So he'll un-invert himself and go to that car and take the device.

Comment: If you think deeper, annihilation is impossible as described in the movie, as you annihilating your past self would create a grandfather paradox which seems to be impossible within the Tenet universe. Hence the scientist likely lied about it or simply speculated - the lack of reliable information is a big part of the film.